# Catch 'Schedule Publish Phases Separately' event in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 GUI

Tags: publishing, cme, 2011-sp1, publishtransaction

I was wondering whether it is possible to know what publishing action an editor has chosen in the GUI.
We are facing a requirement to check the date that is entered at the 'Place Content Online Later' field.

After going through the API documentation, my assumption is that the 'DeployAt' property of the PublishInstruction class contains this information. Is that assumption correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the same event as publishing 'now'.

The difference is simply that the PublishInstruction will have the StartAt property set to the date/time selected for rendering, and the DeployAt property set to the date/time selected for placing the content online.

Answer (score 1):

If an item is scheduled to publish later, it is still entered into the Publishing Queue.  You can use the Core Service to retrieve all items in the Publishing Queue and also get the items scheduled to Publish Later, including information about the item.  Such a script can use a Windows Service.

You can take a look at [my example here of how to query the Publish Queue and also an example of a Windows Service](http://www.curlette.com/?p=1349).